# HasValue and Value

Tags: c#

I noticed something in a code review I did, and am wondering if it's suitable.

```
a.EndDate.HasValue && a.EndDate > paymentPeriodEndDate
```

Shouldn’t that be:

```
a.EndDate.HasValue && a.EndDate.Value > paymentPeriodEndDate
```

Note, a.EndDate is a `DateTime?`, while paymentPeriodEndDate is `DateTime`

Should .Value be used? Or is it OK to omit it. The compiler allows it, and the code works. I then just wonder why there's a .Value available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A nullable is implicitly castable* to it's underlying type, so

```
a.EndDate > paymentPeriodEndDate
```

is implicitly converted to

```
((DateTime)a.EndDate) > paymentPeriodEndDate
```

which calls `.Value` as part of the cast.
Since you're already done a null-check, then there's no practical difference.

> I then just wonder why there's a .Value available.

You would use `Value` when there's no way for the compiler to implicitly know what the expected output is (e.g. when passing to a generic method or a method with overloads).  Since you're comparing to another `DateTime` the compiler can infer your intent and call `.Value` for you.

---

*<sub>Techncially I think the *compiler* adds in a cast since the cast operator from `Nullable<T>` to `T` is `explicit`, but the principle should be the same.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Seems valid. I notice that if you want any 'DateTime' functionality, you need the .Value (To get, maybe 'Milliseconds' or something. So the .Value seems to add more funtionality to the type.

Comment: It is not converted to a simple cast as it would fail when the nullable has no value. A type is implicitly castable to it's nullable but the opposite must be explicit.

Comment: @Craig - yes in order to get to the _properties_ of the underlying type you need to use `.Value`.  The properties of the underlying type are _not_ lifted up to the nullable type.

Answer (score 4):

I would use just `a.EndDate > paymentPeriodEndDate` here, because your code interpreted as such

```
a.EndDate.HasValue && a.EndDate > (DateTime?)paymentPeriodEndDate
```

What you have here is a lifted operator:

> - For the relational operators
>
>   ```
>   <  >  <=  >=
>   ```
>
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator produces the value `false` if one or both operands are null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

As result, you have this:

```
a.EndDate.HasValue && a.EndDate.HasValue && a.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault() > paymentPeriodEndDate
```

So, you actually double check `a.EndDate.HasValue` here.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit `.Value`, because if `a.EndDate` will have no value, then comparison will always return `false`.

But in your code you check that it has value first, so it's safe to assume, that comparison will return the exact result and not a `false` that comes from one argument having no value.

In terms of generated IL code these will probably be almost identical, so there is no performance hit or anything like this involved.